Python webbrowser not opening in pop-up window
I am using Raspberry Pi 4 to run webbrowser.open().  But instead of open pop-up window, it show this in terminal.  After choosing 'A', it shows the webpage content in terminal.  How can I solve?  I have set default browser to Firefox.  I am not sure is it Raspberry Pi or Linux problem.
Edit:
My goal is to open an url in browser to get oauth2 and then auto close the pop-up window.
Now I change to os.system("open <url>").  It opens in pop-window but I cannot auto close it by pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'w').  (pyautogui works when the window is opened by webbrowser.open())



See here, "Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system’s associated program. However, this is neither supported nor portable." .You have to consider using other methods like subprocess.run to specify exact browser,and call it properly with appropriate command instead of using helpers like webbrowser
